# How can I use the Pages Full Screen in the old way?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, pages

I just updated to Mac Maverick and updated Pages.
The question is I just can't get used to it, I don't the exact words to describe it.
In the past, when in the Full Screen modem, I am typing in floating whiteboard in the whole darkness, which is awesome.

How can I do that in the newest version of Pages now?

Answer (score 1):

First, click on "Setup" to toggle the Setup pane off (if it is on).  Then two finger click on the toolbar, and select "Hide Toolbar".

Comment: I just made a silly mistake,http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107804/how-to-recover-my-texts