# How to recover my texts on Pages?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, pages

I just made a big silly mistake
in the newest Pages Version on Mac air, I clicked "setup", then I clicked "Document Body", and then Pages asked me"Are you sure you want to remove the body of the document?",and I said "Yes",and all my stuff just disappeared. There was nothing left.

And I quickly quit the Pages, hoping that there will be a sign asking me "Are you going to save the changes?" and I will click "No"

But such thing did not happen.

How can I recover my texts now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

**File** → **Revert to** → **Browse All Versions**, and there you go.